# Dynamic titles in Apache EChart based on the number of series

Tags: echarts

Is it possible to count the series after using dataZoom options and modify the title of the chart with the count? For example, after using dataZoom, if the series is 15, I want to display "Top 15 cities" or accordingly. I was looking into the datazoom events but it provides only the start and end percentage. Are there any other options?
TIA
Sri